# How to prove that $B = (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So, my professor asked us to prove these statements.
$$
B = (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c)\\
A \cup B = A \cup (B \cap A^c)
$$

I understand the meaning behind these, but I'm completely lost as to how to mathematically prove them.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried showing double containment?

Comment: Since you understand the meaning of these set operations and how they are defined, then simply unpack and apply the definitions. Set equality, e.g, $A = B$ can be proven by proving $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$. Then, for the first, you aim to prove that $a \in A \implies a \in B$. Likewise, for the second, prove that $b \in B \implies b \in A$. Let definitions do the work.

Comment: I think the real key here is to understand how mutual subset inclusion implies equality.

Comment: @MariaSanchez The answers being given are great and correct, but you may have somewhat of a hard time following them. I answered a similar question a while back (proving set properties) where I spelled things out quite carefully and clearly, and you may benefit from my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112545/proving-set-operations/1112596#1112596

Answer (score 2):

You should prove two containments:

1. $B \subset (B ∩ A) ∪ (B ∩ A^c)$ Choose any $x \in B$. Now there  are two cases: $x \in A$ or $x \not\in A$. If $x \in A$ then $x \in B \cap A$, so $x \in (B ∩ A) ∪ (B ∩ A^c)$. If  $x \not\in A$, then $x \in B \cap A^c$, so also $x \in (B ∩ A) ∪ (B ∩ A^c)$. Finally $x \in (B ∩ A) ∪ (B ∩ A^c)$.
2. $(B ∩ A) ∪ (B ∩ A^c) \subset B$ Choose any $x \in (B ∩ A) ∪ (B ∩ A^c)$. Now you also have two cases: $x \in (B ∩ A)$ or $x \in (B ∩ A^c)$. If $x \in (B ∩ A)$, then $x \in B$, if $x \in (B ∩ A^c)$ then also $x \in B$. Finally $x \in B$.

Can you prove the second this way?

Answer (score 1):

$$(B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c)=B \cap (A\cup A^c )=B \cap U = B$$

$$A \cup (B \cap A^c)=  (A \cup B)\cap (A\cup A^c) =(A \cup B)\cap U=(A \cup B) $$

Comment: for associative property (and other laws you may need and I used here) in set theory, see [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** An equality between sets is proved by considering an element in one of the sides and proving (via definitions, axioms, proven theorems and so on) it must be on the other side (by implications or, sometimes, equivalence).

Consider $B = (B\cap A) \cup (B\cap A^c)$. Let's take an element $x\in (B\cap A) \cup (B\cap A^c)$.

$$ x \in (B\cap A) \cup (B\cap A^c) \iff x\in B\cap A \lor x\in B\cap A^c \; (\text{Definition of } \cup)$$
$$ \iff (x\in B \land x\in A)\lor (x\in B\land x\in A^c) \; (\text{Definition of } \cap) $$

Now, from this point on, do you know the definition of $A^c$?, do you know the distributive law between $\land$ and $\lor$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** In showing $B = (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c)$, think of $(B \cap A)$ as "The part of $B$ contained in $A$" and think of  $(B \cap A^c)$ as "the part of $B$ outside of $A$." Convince yourself that the union of the two must be $B$. A Venn Diagram can help tremendously. As for showing this rigorously, show $B \subset  (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c)$ and then show $(B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c) \subset B$ to establish equality of the two.

In showing $A \cup B = A \cup (B \cap A^c)$ simply apply some set algebra to $A \cup (B \cap A^c)$. Use the fact that for sets $X,Y,Z$, we know $X \cup (Y \cap Z) = (X \cup Y) \cap (X \cup Z)$.